# Drupal Private Publishing

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Is there a way to have a content type that is only viewable to admins AND the person who created it, including comments? I feel like I know the answer to this but its escaping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** the content type is defined by your own module, you can use `hook_access` to do this.

If the content type is defined by CCK or another module, things are a bit trickier. You can [install a patch](http://www.johnandcailin.com/blog/cailin/implementing-hookaccess-cck-content-types) that adds an `access` op to `hook_nodeapi`, but unfortunately that's a hack to the core Drupal code, with all the potential upgrade pitfalls that ensue.

Comment: Ah, duh, thats right. Thanks. Not just a basic CCK but one implemented by a module.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [Nodeaccess](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) module. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> Nodeaccess is a Drupal access control module which provides view, edit and delete access to nodes. Users with the 'grant node permissions' permission will have a grant tab on node pages which allows them to grant access to that node by user or role. Administrators can set default access controls per content type, and also define which roles are available to grant permissions to on the node grants tab.
>
> The upshot is, this module allows you to do things like 'node 123 can be viewed by authenticated users and edited by admin users and joeuser'. As an added bonus, update and delete permissions are separated, so you can make sure users with edit permissions cannot accidentally delete pages.